# System.Net.Http.HttpClient with GetAsync().Result not returning all data

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

We have this async call to a API which makes a blocking call with .Result.

The problem here, is that we're not getting all the data, which should have been around 1800 entries.. we're only getting about 16 or 17 pr. call..

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlRecipe2Parameters).Result;  // Blocking call!
       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
           var responseContent = response.Content;
           string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Anyone have any knowledge about this and how to make *sure* that all records are fetched before continuing ?

Terje.

Comment: You should not be doing `.Result` either you need to make your call stack async or use `System.Net.WebClient` and call it's `DownloadString` method to run it syncronously.

Comment: Hmm.. ok. Haven't used that before, but i will probably find some good examples :) Thanks !

Comment: If you want to download async you can read this:
http://rextester.com/discussion/XPKY90132/async-example-with-HttpClient -- I think you are missing `await`

Comment: will read :) thanx!.. This topic can be a bit.... confusing sometimes :)